# GPIO board read/write via bash

Tags: bash, stty, gpio

Trying to get a GPIO board working, need to access it from script, here is what I am using:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM1 115200 raw -echo   #CONFIGURE SERIAL PORT
exec 3</dev/ttyACM1                     #REDIRECT SERIAL OUTPUT TO FD 3
cat <&3 > /tmp/ttyDump.dat &            #REDIRECT SERIAL OUTPUT TO FILE
PID=$!                                  #SAVE PID TO KILL CAT
echo "gpio readall" > /dev/ttyACM1      #SEND COMMAND STRING TO SERIAL PORT
sleep 5s                                #WAIT FOR RESPONSE
kill $PID                               #KILL CAT PROCESS
exec 3<&-                               #FREE FD 3
cat /tmp/ttyDump.dat                    #DUMP CAPTURED DATA
```

The board is working - I can access via screen, enter same command and get results back, so I know its my fractured script.  What am I doing wrong?

Note - this script was copied from elsewhere here on stackexchange.

Comment: When the script finishes (assuming it does), what's in your `ttyDump.dat` file?

Comment: ttyDump.dat is empty, zero length.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the GPIO board's manufacturer and model so that others with the same board might also find your question and answer...

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  First, I had the tty commo configured wrong.  Second, I was sending the command in a way that the GPIO board didn't know what to do with it.  This works:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM1 -cstopb -crtscts cs8 9600 #CONFIGURE SERIAL PORT
exec 3</dev/ttyACM1                            #REDIRECT SERIAL OUTPUT TO FD 3
cat <&3 > /tmp/ttyDump.dat &                   #REDIRECT SERIAL OUTPUT TO FILE
PID=$!                                         #SAVE PID TO KILL CAT
#  echo "Process ID is $PID"
printf "gpio read 0\r" > /dev/ttyACM1          #SEND COMMAND STRING TO SERIAL PORT
sleep .2s                                      #WAIT FOR RESPONSE
kill $PID                                      #KILL CAT PROCESS
exec 3<&-                                      #FREE FD 3
cat /tmp/ttyDump.dat                           #DUMP CAPTURED DATA
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide a link to the board's programming API website, if there is one....

Comment: Board MFG link is here: https://numato.com/docs/8-channel-usb-gpio-module-with-analog-inputs/